# Displaying checkbox state on page load

Tags: javascript

I assembled some code that checks the state of a checkbox and then displays the corresponding message as a string. The default state of the checkbox is "unchecked", but when I reload the page there's no message displaying "Unchecked", it will work as intended once I check the checkbox and uncheck. I want the state to display on page load in a nutshell, not on-change. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" />
<div id="text"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var getId = document.getElementById('text'),
    checkbox = document.getElementById('checkBox');

function checkState(){
    text.innerHTML = checkbox.checked ? "Checkbox is checked" : "Checkbox is empty";
}
checkbox.onchange = checkState;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a server side scripting language to do this.

Comment: @Asad, you're wrong, check the answers bellow.

Comment: @Whiteagle I guess I misunderstood the question, but I thought he wanted for the state of the checkbox to be preserved when he reloaded the page. This **cannot** be done without storing information server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call your own function in addiction to set it as the checkbox `onchange` event.

Since you're executing the script on the end of the body, it only gets executed when you already have access to the DOM, you just need to call `checkState()` after it's definition.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" />
<div id="text"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var getId = document.getElementById('text'),
    checkbox = document.getElementById('checkBox');

function checkState(){
    text.innerHTML = checkbox.checked ? "Checkbox is checked" : "Checkbox is empty";
}
checkbox.onchange = checkState;
checkState();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're running the function as an `onchange` handler. That is the event which fires when the state of the checkbox changes, as you have seen. You said:

> I want the state to display on page load in a nutshell, not on-change.

Then the fix should be *pretty darn obvious:* change the `checkbox.onchange` to a `window.onload`.